# $P(X_i\leq C_i\leq Y_i)\geq1-2\alpha$ implies $P(\sum_{i=1}^kl_iX_i\leq \sum_{i=1}^kl_iC_i\leq \sum_{i=1}^kl_iY_i)\geq1-2\alpha$??

Tags: probability

Suppose $$P(X_i\leq C_i\leq Y_i)\geq1-2\alpha$$, where $i=1,\ldots,k$, $k$ finite number,$0\leq\alpha\leq$1/2, $X_i,Y_i$ are random variable and $C_i$ real number.

Then is it true that, $$P(\sum_{i=1}^kl_iX_i\leq \sum_{i=1}^kl_iC_i\leq \sum_{i=1}^kl_iY_i)\geq1-2\alpha$$, where $l_i$ are positive constants??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is true. For example, consider random variables $X_i$ with half probability being $0$ and half being $1$, and $Y_i$ with half probability being $1$ and half being $2$. Then, we consider the case $k=2$, $\alpha = \frac{1}{4}$ and $C_1 = C_2 = \frac{2}{5}$. We may derive the following: $$P(X_1\leq C_1 \leq Y_1) = \frac{1}{2}\geq 1-2\alpha$$ $$P(X_2\leq C_2 \leq Y_2) = \frac{1}{2}\geq 1- 2\alpha$$
However, $$P(X_1+X_2\leq C_1+C_2=0.8 \leq Y_1+Y_2) = P(X_1+X_2\leq 0.8) = \frac{1}{4}$$
which is not greater or equal to $1-2\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$.